# How to translate "far right" and "far left" (politics)?

Tags: single-word-requests

How would one translate "far left" or "far right", in the context of politics.  My thought was *Ekstrema (mal)dekstro*, but that feels somewhat more extreme than *far left* or *far right*.

Answer (score 7):

It seems good enough for Monato:

- la ekstremdekstra Nacia Alianco
- ekstrema dekstrismo
- ekstremdekstrulaj politikistoj
- la franca ekstremdekstra partio Fronto Nacia (FN)
- ekstremismaj kontraŭfremdulaj dekstruloj
- la ekstremdekstra Libereca Partio
- la ekstreme dekstra HSP
- RV (ekstrem-maldekstra balotkoalicio) plendis

Comment: What is "Monato"?

Comment: It's a monthly news magazine in Esperanto. There is a large collections of Monato articles in tekstaro.com and most of the hits I found were from that source. There were a few from La Ondo de Esperanto as well.

Comment: More texts than in Tekstaro you can find in the website of Monato itself: www.monato.net Check the finder on the left of every page.

Answer (score 4):

> **Dekstra ekstremismo** and **forta dekstra ekstremismo** https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekstra_ekstremismo
>
> **Maldekstra ekstremismo** https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maldekstra_ekstremismo

Also, these two wikis may be of interest to you:

- https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politika_dekstro
- https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politika_maldekstro

Some cultures may not understand the term left wing or right wing, therefore, it may be more useful to just say conservative or liberal.

Conservative - Against change and reform

> **Konservativa:** Politike kaj socie konservema; kontraŭa al ŝanĝoj kaj reformoj - http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/konser1.html#konser1.0a

Liberal - Accepting and tolerant of differences

> **Liberala:** Favora al libero kaj toleremo en sociaj, politikaj, religiaj aferoj - http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/libera.html#libera.0a.POL

Comment: "Liberal" is no more international than "left". In America it seems synonymous with "left", an America way of saying "social democrat" whereas in Europe it often means someone who privileges freedom and equality of opportunity over other goals.

Comment: @conor The tekstaro has several entries for the word "Liberala"